# wpf element name as an argument for IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter, data-binding

I am trying to get multilingual translation("label or caption") string value for the given elementname in wpf.
For example; for elementname "txtDescription" ; my IValueConverter implementation will return with "Description" ; for another language will return different translation string(i.e. descripción for Spanish) and the translation string will be Text=... of the same element.

I am new to wpf; I cant make it work. Is there any elegant way to do that with similiar manner as below.

```
<TextBlock Name="txtDescription" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MultiLingualConverter} }"</TextBlock>
```

If this is not simple or requires more code then as an alternative sending "txtDescription" as an argument to MultiLingualConverter is acceptable but I dont now how to do that neither.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? An unexpected result? Something else? One thing I noticed is there is a syntactical error in your code; you are not closing your tag properly, which wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, you should build good localization support in your system, better then using converter for every string.

Until today, the best solution i have found and i almost always use it is this:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection/

give it a try. good luck

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I really liked it, even I wont use it as-is , it provides the whole logic which I can use for my scenerio(Pulling multilingual resources from web server at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the element name via the ConverterParameter property, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752275(v=vs.110).aspx) is an example of how it is used to pass a string to the converter.

However, WPF localization is more than returning different strings for different languages. You can read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information and there is a Run Dialog Box example in the page to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Due to cyclical dependency restrictions you cannot reference a control inside   itself or its descendants in the tree.
I would recommend you not to use converter for multilingual support. it is not a best way to do this.
got here for best way to do.
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650(v=vs.110).aspx